# Extracting algebraic constraints from the input data

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, training

I would appreciate your help with this (naive) question of mine.

Given the set of points located on a circle, $x_{i}, y_{i}$ as the input data, Can a deep/machine learning algorithm infer that radius of the circle is constant ? In other words, given the data $x_{i}, y_{i}$ is there way that algorithm discovers the constraint: $x_{i}^2 + y_{i}^2 = \text{constant}$ ?

I would also appreciate any related reference on the subject.

Comment: No, I am not aiming to discover attractors in phase space, but in general I would like to discover algebraic constraints hidden in the data. The circle example is the simplest one I could think of.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it with [ACE](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.1985.10478157) (alternating conditional expectations) - an algorithm that searches for transformations

$$\theta(y) = f_1(x_1)+f_2(x_2)+...+f_n(x_n)$$
The functions $\theta$, and $f_i$ are estimated from data. I'll give an example in R here. There is also a [package in Python](https://github.com/partofthething/ace) that does ACE.

Let's generate some data

```
np <- 100 # number of points
R <- runif(np, min = 0.9, max = 1.1)
alpha <- runif(np, min = 0.0, max = 2*pi)
x <- R*cos(alpha)
y <- R*sin(alpha)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
plot(x,y)
```

[image]

ACE to estimate $\theta(y) = f(x)$:

```
library(acepack)
a <- ace(x,y, delrsq = 0.0001)
```

See the transforms, $\theta$, and $f$

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(a$x,a$tx)
plot(a$y,a$ty)
```

[image]

They look like parabolas, so let's fit them.

```
xx<-drop(a$x)
yy<-drop(a$tx)

plot(xx,yy)
m.x <- lm(yy ~ xx+I(xx^2))
xnew=sort(xx)
lines(xnew, predict(m.x, list(xx=xnew)),col="red",lwd=2)

xx<-drop(a$y)
yy<-drop(a$ty)

plot(xx,yy)
m.y <- lm(yy ~ xx+I(xx^2))
m.y$coefficients
xnew=sort(xx)
lines(xnew, predict(m.y, list(xx=xnew)),col="red",lwd=2)
```

[image]

The red parabolas don't go through the transforms exactly but we don't need it. We use them only as hints to find the exact relations. We can tweak the parameters later. The parameters of our approximate fits are

```
m.x$coefficients

(Intercept)          xx     I(xx^2) 
 1.31459869  0.07527254 -2.55098259
```

which means $f(x) \approx  1.3-2.56 x^2$

```
m.y$coefficients
 (Intercept)           xx      I(xx^2) 
-1.342572495  0.001216412  2.791683219
```

which means $\theta(y) \approx -1.3 + 2.8 y^2$

So, we have 
$$-1.3 + 2.8 y^2 \approx 1.3-2.56 x^2$$
or
$$2.56 x^2 + 2.8 y^2 \approx 2.6 $$

From here you can recover $x^2+y^2 = 1$